# Apple's new Kids Section parental control issue

Tags: ios

I am updating my kids app for compliance to Apple's new Kids section. I have read the updated Review Guidelines. And it says :

> Apps primarily intended for use by kids under 13 must get parental
>   permission or use a parental gate before allowing the user to link out
>   of the app or engage in commerce

Does anybody have any idea about what kind of action to take? How can we get parental permission or use a parental gate? Besides I am linking out just to apps iTunes page and our social pages, so do I need to take any action?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through [this topic](https://devforums.apple.com/message/869675#869675) on the Apple developer forums, where someone suggested the following for in-app purchases:

```
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
    // user can make purchases
} else {
   // no purchases can be made, show error or just don't show the in app purchase button(s)
}
```

If there is a way to determine if in-app purchases have been enabled on the device, is there a way to determine if Safari has been enabled?

Also, [this article](http://www.appsplayground.com/apps/2013/08/19/apple-ios7-app-store-kids-category/) mentions PINs that must be entered before links can be opened, as well as requiring a three-finger swipe for in-app purchases / parents' sections.

These options may be worth a try, but I don't know if they will be enough.

Comment: Yes, when it comes to in-app purchases, you could check if it is restricted on that device. But as far as I know, parental control comes to Safari with iOS7. And about entering PIN or three-finger swipe, I think it would be activated/deactivated via iOS' Settings App. This article mentions the same "iOS 7 includes an option to limit certain web content by age level as well." http://osxdaily.com/2013/07/20/restrictions-parental-controls-ios/

Comment: Here are examples of how real kids app companies are solving the problem and not getting rejected.

http://blog.momswithapps.com/2013/08/20/how-are-kids-app-developers-communicating-to-parents/

What we need is guidance from Apple on what they exactly want, and they could make it part of their SDK.  It could be a boolean that you attach to any UI element. parentGate = YES;

Comment: How could any of those solutions would help apps to be approved? Most children over 6-7 will be able to pass that verifications. If they work, Apple is just wasting our and reviewers' time.

Answer (score 5):

I thumbed through the [FAQ](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/faqs) and the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/1_Introduction/Introduction.html) myself and Apple certainly doesn't make it clear what "must get parental permission" means, but I *suspect* what this means is that the App Store will require some kind of extra authentication steps in order to do commerce (i.e. in-app purchases) or go somewhere outside of the app (e.g. with a UIWebView).

Which seems to be make sense because of this statement:  *"must get parental permission or use a parental gate before allowing the user to link out of the app or engage in commerce"*.

Comment: I agree, it is certainly not clear at all. Current "Restrictions" at the settings already handles in-app purchases, and when using an UIWebView, mostly it is required to rate the app +17. My concern is about the linking out to Safari thing. But I think as Kids section will be available with iOS7 and Safari on iOS7 will have built-in Parental Controls, this should not be developers' concern. So, what is the action that we have to take about it, not clear.

Comment: I think the most important "take away" (thing for us to remember) is that the old "Kids" games subcategory is going away in favor of new Kids category with age ranges of "5 & under", "6-8" and "9-11" and that developers (or our employers) need to choose the correct age range for each app.

Comment: Yes, choosing the range is a total headache. For instance, my app is also suitable for kids under 6 with parental assistance, but now I have to choose 6-8 range. Not good.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same thing, as I'm not entirely sure if this is under NDA I asked this question on the apple developer forums, but no reply there either.

As far as I know there is no "set of API's" which define parental permission / parental gate, so the requirements are very vague indeed.

I fear we'll just have to try things and submit for approval, and find out in blogposts of various developers (and answers here on stackoverflow) what gets you rejected and what not, I hope I'm wrong and they clear this out though.

Anyway, I just updated one of our apps and checked the "Made for kids", it's in "waiting for review" now, if anything out of the ordinary happens I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Same thing here, i have also uploaded an update and it is waiting for review. I kept out-going links to our social networks, and link to iTunes for app rating, added a Privacy Policy url at iTunes Connect. I will keep here updated.

Answer (score 2):

As I have mentioned before, I had uploaded an update (keeping the outgoing links to social pages and to App Store for app rating via an UIAlertView) and the update is rejected as well.

At Resolution Center, it was mentioned clearly that because these outgoing links were not passing through a Parental Gate my app was rejected, and two screenshots were attached which show the buttons and UIAlertView leading out off the app. So don't forget to check the Resolution Center.

I have removed all out-going links and uploading the app again. I will keep here updated.

And the Parental Gate thing. I think I have found out how it will be working. Apple leaves this completely to developers. We will have to be using API's or SDK's of Parental Gate providers or services. With the help of such API's we will pass the urls to these parental gate services via their API's, and they will approve or reject the link (by checking their database) or they will require a parent's input, and possibly they will return a true/false flag, or let the user continue to the link.

For instance, a parental gate service is working on such thing :
http://parentalgate.com/parental-gate-ios-sdk/

> My update with out-going links removed is approved. It took 20 minutes to get reviewed after waiting for review for 8 days.